# sql getting a complex average function

Tags: sql

i m trying to get this:

"Create a view that lists ALL foods with a total consumption for one week. This view is used to help order the food for the zoo animals to eat. Show the food id and name, along with the weekly consumption, the number of animals being fed with each food and the average consumption (weekly consumption divided by number of animals that eat that food) of the food by each animal."

below is my sql query:

```
SELECT a.foodID
      ,NAME
      ,b.qtyperday * 7 AS "weekly consumption"
      ,COUNT(animalID)
      ,AVG(( b.qtyperday * 7) / COUNT(animalID))
       AS "average consumption"
FROM food a, feed b
WHERE a.foodID = b.foodID
GROUP BY foodID
```

i can't seem to be able to generate any data for the average consumption which is the final condition
, any solutions??

Comment: Although it probably doesn't make a difference for this question, you should also add the tag for the DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle? SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to get the number of distinct animals for each food, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.foodID
      ,NAME
      ,b.qtyperday * 7 AS "weekly consumption"
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT animalID)
       AS "animals eating this food"
      ,AVG(( b.qtyperday * 7) / COUNT(DISTINCT animalID))
       AS "average consumption"
FROM food a, feed b
WHERE a.foodID = b.foodID
GROUP BY foodID
```

But for further help I think you need to post some sample data and some expected outputs.